# Better way to write this javascript filter code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

A reject function which is passed a sub array of numbers array, should reject whatever is in that sub array. Also if there is a way to just write one reject function and eliminate greaterthanvalues function and its result.

How to shorten this code further. Any help is appreciated.

```
var numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var greaterthanvalues = (numbers, value) => numbers.filter((number) => number > value )
var t = greaterthanvalues(numbers, 5)
var reject = (numbers) =>  
           numbers.filter((number) => number < t[0]) 
reject(numbers, greaterthanvalues)
```

Comment: This might be a better candidate for CodeReviewSE

Comment: Please share the description of your code.

Comment: Sorry, added description. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: "is passed a sub array of numbers array" This needs to be rephrased.  What is a "sub array of numbers array"?

Comment: There is an array in the code called numbers array. var numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; greaterthanvalues function creates a sub array, which instead is passed to the reject function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on why you're doing what you're doing with this code. If you're just trying to golf it, one way to make it shorter is to remove the definitions of the lambdas and call them inline. Something like below

```
var numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var greaterthanvalues = ((numbers, value) => numbers.filter((number) => number > value ))(numbers, 5)
var reject = ((numbers) => numbers.filter((number) => number < greaterthanvalues[0]))(numbers, greaterthanvalues)
```

Updated answer to reflect your comments/edits

```
var numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var reject = (numbers, lambdaRet) => numbers.filter((number) => number < lambdaRet[0])
reject(numbers, ((numbers, value) => numbers.filter((number) => number > value ))(numbers, 5))
```

Explanation: Without rewriting the entire idea of what you're doing, here's one method of getting there. Reject is a function which takes two arrays as its parameters. When calling this function, I passed in the first array as numbers, and the second one as the result of the lambda function I defined and called inline. This should give you a good baseline to go off

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to not write greaterthanvalues and instead merge it inside the reject function ?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect something like that. Passing in the original numbers array and the result of a lambda function